# Selection sort review. Does it look good?

Tags: c

I always wanted to ask this but couldn't for some reason.

I had written this chunk of code about 3 months ago when one of my teacher explained what selection sort was using flow chart. I had a basic understanding of what arrays were. So I sat down and wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER 10

void selection_sort(int [], int []);

void selection_sort(int num[], int sorted[])
{
    int i, high = 0, k, j = 9, store;

    for(k = 0; k < MAX_NUMBER; k++)
    {
      for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER; i++)
      {
         if(num[i] > high)
         {
             high = num[i];
             store = i;
         }
      }

      sorted[j] = high; // Place the highest number in the end of array and decrement array
      j--;
      num[store] = 0; // Place 0 in the place of maximum number that was in the array
      high = 0; // again make high as zero, so as to compare zerpo again with all the numbers that are in the array
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num[MAX_NUMBER], sorted[MAX_NUMBER];
    int i;

    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", MAX_NUMBER);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    selection_sort(num, sorted);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER; i++)
      printf("%d ", sorted[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

and I took almost 30 minutes to write this. But as you know the program in text books are a lot faster and smaller.

Can you please tell me what kind of programmer I can become? I have been programming for a good 6 months now.

This code review monster got into my head after reading Steve McConnell: Code Complete. Still I have a lot of pages to go through.

Answer (score 3):

- You don't need two arrays, it works with one too, simply swap the
  values. This needs less memory.
- According to this:

  ```
  int i, high = 0, k, j = 9, store;
  ```

  `j` is always one less than the size of the array. Don't use magic numbers, use the constant.
- If you want to reuse this `selection_sort` it would be adviseable to
  add a parameter for the size, so you don't need the global constant.
- In the inner loop you also iterate through the array parts which also have been sorted. (This may also be the reason you choose to use two arrays)
- The result may be wrong if you'd only have negative values in the array (due `high = 0`)

Here my improved implementation:

```
void selection_sort(int *num, size_t size)
{
    size_t k, i, j, store; // for indexes
    int high, swap; // for values

    // no need to sort if the array is short enough
    if(size <= 1) return;

    high = INT_MIN; // set the highest number to the minium
    j = size - 1;

    for(k = 0; k < size; k++, j--)
    {
      for(i = 0; i <= j; i++)
      {
         if(num[i] >= high)
         {
             high = num[i];
             store = i;
         }
      }

      // swap the highest number with the number at the last position
      // in the array
      swap = num[j]; 
      num[j] = num[store]; 
      num[store] = swap;
      high = INT_MIN; // reset the highest number
    }
}
```

There is also a similar implementation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answer , i would suggest

```
int i;
int high = 0;
int k;
int j = 9;
int store;
```

instead of single line declarations.

```
int i, high = 0, k, j = 9, store;
```

The former way , may take more space , but is convenient for adding a comment to each declaration and for improves readability for subsequent modifications.

Also [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23657/improving-my-game-code/23668#23668) , makes a valid reason not to prefer single line declarations.

One more point is that , generally in most code i have seen , functions are declared before main() and defined after main().

So your program must look like,

```
void selection_sort(int [], int []);                //Declaration


int main()
{

retrun 0;
}

void selection_sort(int num[], int sorted[])        //Definition
{

}
```